# <Empty string> pops up when search in file in IntelliJ IDEA IDE

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, jetbrains-ide

[image]

At some point search in file started showing me this "Empty string" tooltips everywhere I search and there is no way to get rid of them unless I close the tooltip or search for another word

Does anyone know how to turn this off, because it's very disturbing and unpleasant to see every time I search for some specific word?

Answer (score 2):

This particular scenario is only for search and replace window (Ctrl + R) with regular expression.

Try searching by `Ctrl + F` instead of `Ctrl + R`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was always searching by  `Ctrl + F`, but the regex checkbox was checked, I unchecked it and no mpre tooltip popups.

Comment: I like using the regex search, but I don't want to see these pop ups. I would still like to know how to turn it off.